# How do I uninstall IE 10 and get back IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, downgrade

I recently installed IE 10 on Windows 7. The initial install was smooth and all looked good, until I opened a website (cnn.com) and got a blank screen. So I decided that the pre-release was not ready, and decided to uninstall it and reinstall IE9.

This is where the problems started. I thought I had removed IE 10 from my system, but when I tried to install IE 9, it said I had a more recent IE version and the installation stopped.

So I thought I should remove the Internet Explorer folder and got an error message about TrustedInstaller. So I took ownership of the folder for my userid (John). Now when starting Windows Explorer I get the following message:

> You need permission to perform this action: You require permission from John-PC\john

I just gave ownership of the folder and its subfolders to John-PC\john.

How can I get back IE 9?

Comment: When you remove the IE 10 update, it leaves with you 9. There was no reason to try to re-install 9.

Comment: This is the reason you should not take ownership of system files.  You will need to use a system restore point and/or run 'sfc scannow` and hope you can fix your problem without reinstall Windows.

Comment: I agree with the "just use Chrome" but for testing we unfortunately need several versions of IE. I was able to find ieexplore.exe in program files and start it. However there is no navigation when I enter a URL. I think the problem started when I started up the Developer Tools but not sure what that would do.